# A question about Central Limit Theorem and the calculation of a limit.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

The question is the next:

> **Using CLT** to calculate
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{8^n}{27^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{3n}{k}\frac{1}{2^k}$$
> I have started by defining a sequence $X_n$ of random variables with $X_n$~$Bin\left(3,\frac{1}{3}\right)$ then if $S_n=X_1+ \ldots + X_n$, $S_n$~$Bin\left(3n,\frac{1}{3}\right)$
> From here I am stuck and have no idea how to apply CLT, the answer marked in the book is
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{8^n}{27^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{3n}{k}\frac{1}{2^k}=0$$
> But I don't know how it could give $0$, any advice or help, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{8}{27}\right)^n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{3n}{k} \frac{1}{2^k}
= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{3n}{k} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^k \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{3n-k}
= \mathbf{P}(S_{3n} \leq n),
\end{align*}

where $S_{3n} \sim \operatorname{Bin}(3n, \frac{1}{3})$. So by the CLT,

$$ \mathbf{P}(S_{3n} \leq n) = \mathbf{P}\left(\frac{S_{3n} - \mathbf{E}[S_{3n}]}{\sqrt{\mathbf{Var}(S_{3n})}} \leq 0 \right) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \mathbf{P}(Z \leq 0) = \frac{1}{2}, $$

where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ is a standard normal variable. I also included the graph of this quantity as a function of $n$:

[image: graph]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that was the part where I was having problems :)